# Flattening an array of complex objects with an array attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

i was wondering if there is quick solution (using map() for example) to convert  a multidimensional array to a single dimensional array, that still keeps all information of the original array.

You can solve it with some loops, but i think there must be a smarter solution.

To explain it a bit more here is an example:

```
const arr = [{
  id: 1,
  people: [
    {name: "x", surname: "x"},
    {name: "y", surname: "y"}
  ]
 },{
  id: 2,
  people: [
    {name: "a", surname: "a"},
    {name: "b", surname: "b"}
  ]
 }]

const result = [
 {id: 1, name: "x", surname: "x"},
 {id: 1, name: "y", surname: "y"},
 {id: 2, name: "a", surname: "a"},
 {id: 2, name: "b", surname: "b"}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.flatMap()` with an internal `Array.map()` to add the `id`:

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"people":[{"name":"x","surname":"x"},{"name":"y","surname":"y"}]},{"id":2,"people":[{"name":"a","surname":"a"},{"name":"b","surname":"b"}]}]
 
const result = arr.flatMap(({ id, people }) => people.map(p => ({ id, ...p })))

console.log(result)
```

If `Array.flatMap()` is not supported by your target browsers, use `Array.map()`, and spread into `Array.concat()`:

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"people":[{"name":"x","surname":"x"},{"name":"y","surname":"y"}]},{"id":2,"people":[{"name":"a","surname":"a"},{"name":"b","surname":"b"}]}]
 
const result = [].concat(...arr.map(({ id, people }) => people.map(p => ({ id, ...p }))))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Is there a smart way to add the `id` to every object in the array? flatMap() does the right think but the `id` field is lost.

Comment: Missed that. You just need to map the people as well, and add the id. See update.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `map()` and `flat()`

```js
const arr = [{
  id: 1,
  people: [
    {name: "x", surname: "x"},
    {name: "y", surname: "y"}
  ]
 },{
  id: 2,
  people: [
    {name: "a", surname: "a"},
    {name: "b", surname: "b"}
  ]
 }]

const result = arr.map(p => {
  return p.people.map(pi => Object.assign(pi, {id: p.id}));
}).flat();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.reduce` to create multiple entries for each `people`, assuming the array never changes its form.
Further comments about how it works are directly in the code.

```js
const arr = [{
  id: 1,
  people: [
    {name: "x", surname: "x"},
    {name: "y", surname: "y"}
  ]
 },{
  id: 2,
  people: [
    {name: "a", surname: "a"},
    {name: "b", surname: "b"}
  ]
 }]

// Reduce the origianal array.
const r = arr.reduce((acc, {id, people}) => {
  // For each people, push a new elemen to the array.
  return people.forEach(_people => {
    // the element pushed will hold the [id] and all the properties of the currently looped [people] item.
    acc.push(Object.assign({id}, _people));
  }), acc; // <-- finally, return the accumulator for the next iteration.
}, []); // <-- provide a new empty array as an initial value.
console.log(r);
```